# Java String intern By Default

Tags: java

In C# I would have to explictly call String.Intern(string) in order to add a string to the intern pool.

Does Java have the same idea conceptually?  is the expectation that those dealing with frequently and repeatable strings use the intern pool for accessing and resolving strings?

Comment: Java does have the idea of interned string pool and the method intern() in String class, check it out here. [intern()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern())

Answer (score 3):

Java makes short lived objects pretty cheap.  Java 8 can eliminate them entirely. Interning them is fairly expensive and could slow down an application if not used with care.

For longer term objects there is plans to make the `char[]` which the String refers to "interned" on a GC.  The String object itself cannot be interned automagically as this might change behaviour.